# Faster folder transfer over WiFi network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-transfer

I have two PCs, one is connected to my router NetGear DGN3500 directly with cable and the other through WiFi interface, this PC can not be connected with direct cable and it also the PC has the folders and files I need to copy to first PC.

My problem I am transferring many big files and folders and the transfer rate is very slow, it is fixed at 1.6 MB/s so I am looking for a method or tool that can allow me to transfer at higher speed.

I found some info on the internet about setting up IIS but I can not setup this server on the PC that has the files so I appreciate if there is any other solution.

Both PCs running Windows 7 (one is 32bit and the other is 64bit)

Comment: What kind of Wi-Fi do you have on the wireless client PC? What rate does Windows say the PC is connecting to the wireless network at? Do you have 40MHz channels enabled on the router? Did you pick a (pair of) clean channel(s) for the router? If your wireless PC is capable of the same 300Mbps data rate as that router, if you can optimize your settings and RF conditions, you could see about a 10x speedup. Why can't the wireless PC be connected with a direct cable?

Comment: I will answer what I know now. The router mode is set to 300 Mbps, Wireless Router Radio enabled, SSID Broadcast enabled, Wireless Isolation enabled. About channel I did not pick one but it was set to "11". The PC that is connected through Wifi is celeron, old and has problems, Wifi connection is 802.11n @ 54 Mbps. What I should do for optimization ?

Comment: It's strange that it would say it's 802.11n @ 54Mbps, since 54Mbps was the top data rate of 802.11g. If you have wireless security enabled on the router, make sure it's set for WPA2 (AES-CCMP), not original WPA (TKIP). Also, make sure WMM (QoS) is enabled on the router, if you have that option. Can you move the wireless machine to between 2-4 meters of the router (not too close, you could overload the radio receivers, but not too far away, where you stop getting the best data rates). Is there any way you can find out the exact Wi-Fi chipset model number for that laptop?

Comment: I can not move the laptop, it has atheros ar5007eg.

Comment: Atheros ar5007eg is a b/g chip. Its top data rate is 54Mbps, which, after overhead, will be 27Mbps or less, which is 3.2MiB/sec. You could use inSSIDer to try to find a cleaner channel, but if you can't move the AP or the wireless machine closer to each other, there probably isn't a lot you can do to improve things much without upgrading your equipment. A fully modern AP is $180, and a fully modern USB Wi-Fi dongle is $70. Together, they could speed things up by 10x or more.

Comment: @Spiff many thanks for advices and taking the time to replay.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a modern USB wifi adapter that supports all the modern protocols.  Disable the built-in wifi.

Answer (score 0):

A. Improve Wi-Fi connection between PCs and access point/wireless router

- select a less crowded channel / band
- remove devices competing for airtime (Bluetooth)
- decrease distance
- remove solid/metal obstacles
- replace Wi-Fi components for faster ones

B. Decrease amount of data by compression (7-Zip, ...)

C. Replace Wi-Fi connection

- run a (temporary) cable
- use power-line communication
- use USB storage for sneakernet